How to Search with DataType.BINARY_VECTOR in Milvus
I am trying to search using DataType.BINARY_VECTOR in Milvus while computing Hamming distance. However, when executing the client.search method, I encounter an error. My code creates a collection with a binary vector schema, inserts binary vector data, builds a BIN_FLAT index with Hamming as the metric type, and attempts a search using binary vectors. Despite following these steps, the search fails. How should the data parameter be specified for searching with binary vectors in this scenario?
Here is my code snippet:
from pymilvus import MilvusClient, DataType
from pathlib import Path
import numpy as np

DB_FILE = 'demo.db'
DIM = 4096
COLLECTION_NAME = 'dim_reduction'
METRIC_TYPE = 'HAMMING'
INDEX_TYPE = 'BIN_FLAT'
DATATYPE = DataType.BINARY_VECTOR
DTYPE = np.bool_

# Remove DB_FILE if exists
db_path = Path(DB_FILE)
if db_path.exists():
    db_path.unlink()

# Build client
client = MilvusClient(DB_FILE)

# Create schema
schema = MilvusClient.create_schema()
schema.add_field(field_name="id", datatype=DataType.INT64, is_primary=True)
schema.add_field(field_name='text', datatype=DataType.VARCHAR, max_length=1024)
schema.add_field(field_name='vector', datatype=DATATYPE, dim=DIM)

# Create collection
client.create_collection(
    collection_name=COLLECTION_NAME,
    schema=schema,
)

# Insert data
data = [
    {'id': i, 'vector': np.array([1] * DIM, dtype=DTYPE), 'text': f'doc {i}'}
    for i in range(100)
]
client.insert(collection_name=COLLECTION_NAME, data=data)

# Create index
index_params = MilvusClient.prepare_index_params()
index_params.add_index(
    field_name='vector',
    metric_type=METRIC_TYPE,
    index_type=INDEX_TYPE,
)
client.create_index(
    collection_name=COLLECTION_NAME,
    index_params=index_params,
)

    # Search
search_params = {
    'metric_type': METRIC_TYPE,
    'params': {},
}

result = client.search(
    collection_name=COLLECTION_NAME,
    data=[np.array([1] * DIM, dtype=DTYPE)],
    limit=2,
    search_params=search_params,
)
print(result)


I would like to know how many rows are in this collection.
